# Is BFFS! item affecting Lilith's damage?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

As [Platinum God](http://platinumgod.co.uk) states, BFFS! pickup makes your familiars do more damage. Lilith's incubus definitely seems to be enlarged after picking up the item, but does it's damage increase too?

While it seems reasonable that Incubus is also affected, its tears size does not increase. Other damage amplifying effects do change Incubus' tears size, hence my question.

Missing HUD2 stats stay the same after picking up BFFS!, but maybe familiar's damage is calculated differently, and *after* damage calculation of a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Rebirth wikia, [BFFS!](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/BFFS!) increases the size and doubles damage of familiars. So it seems reasonable that **Incubus** is also affected.

Missing HUD2 calculates only your player actual stats, and since BFFS! affects only *Incubus* familiar you won't see any change.

That's why you see a similar behaviour if you pick up [A Lump of Coal](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/A_Lump_Of_Coal), tears gain a flat damage bonus based on how far they travel, it does not affect your base damage.

Comment: While it seems reasonable that Incubus is also affected, his (hers?) tears size does not increase. Other damage amplifying effects do change Incubus' tears size, hence my question. Appended this to my question.

Comment: @Asunez I've found this [Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/3r5rn9/afterbirth_does_the_bffs_enhaces_incubus_damage/)

Comment: @Asunez actually Tears' size does increase on Incubus with BFF! I tested this on yesterday's daily run with Samson+Incubus+Death's Touch+BFF! and the sickles shot by Incubus where twice the size of mine, dealing also increased damage.

Comment: @Kappei Maybe that's the case with sickles, where the size increase is easily visible, but with normal tears I could hardly say one can see the difference. Nevertheless, this proves Pinckerman's answer true, so the green tick of gratitude is yours, Pinckerman